# Snap apps not starting after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: snap, 20.04

I recently noticed that some snap apps like postman or whatsdesk are not starting after I click their icons. Also before upgrading I was able to locater whatsdesk in terminal, now I can't.

I tried starting postman with command `snap run postman` but at first it showed `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"`. Running `DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 snap run postman` helped.

It strange that i.e. Intellij Idea works perfectly as previously.

How can fix app shortcuts?

Comment: The easiest approach may be to just remove and reinstall the application. Your user configuration data is preserved doing so.

Comment: Actually it was the first solution that came to my mind and it didnt't help.